# Stoning a person to death, without stones?

Tags: weapons, spaceships

So, on a far away planet, a group of about 500 kids who were raised on a spaceship has landed. Well, their not ***actually*** children, just people who still have the mentality of children. Most of them are actually around the age of 14. They start building a small, agrarian-ish community, when all hell breaks lose. You see, the 500 kids are split up into 3 caste, a laborer and defender caste, an intellectual caste, and a breeding caste. The laborers, with some help, take over the entire community with their access to guns. The put both other caste into enslavement, and take over. After about a month or two, the cheaply made earth guns all fail, and the laborers must come up with a new way to execute others. They think about stoning peoples death, but for some odd reason, no stones small enough to be thrown exist around the place. So they must try something else. What could you substitute a “Stone” for in the stoning process?

-The place their in is nearly exactly like a Southwestern desert, without the small stones the stones

Comment: Before answering, clarification is needed: 1) Are they all adults with a mind development of a 14yo? Or are they actual 14 yo kids? Your premise is a bit confusing. Thank you

Comment: @Valerio Pastore: 14yo with development of 6 year olds

Comment: Kids don't tend to think categorically "what are some ways to do X?" That's adult thinking. Kids tend to be a bit more flexible and immediate "Hey. let's throw them off that cliff!". Any adolescent can think of *plenty* of gruesome and creative ways to kill somebody.

Comment: Throw the guns at the accused!

Comment: *their (should be "they're" or "they are") not actually children* I know of no place where a 14 year old would be considered anything but a child.

Comment: @StephenG: A 14 year old is commonly considered a young adult.

Comment: *the 500 kids are split up into 3 caste, a laborer and defender caste, an intellectual caste* Sounds extremely unlikely for kids of that age (or mentally younger !).  Kids just don't think in those terms - as @user535733 said you are applying adult thinking to children.

Comment: @StephenG: The robots who raised them told them whatthiier roles would be!

Comment: The term "young adult" is nonsense.  It means a child old enough to be expected to start learning about the adult world.  It does **not** mean they are considered adult.  They are legally defined as "minors" and considered incapable of acting as adults or accepting adult responsibilities for most purposes.

Comment: I won't labor the point, but if you've ever seen a school full of young teens, *telling* them anything has as much effect as the next thought that randomly enters their heads.  Teens are rebellious by nature - they will almost invariably reject roles they are forced into.

Comment: @StephenG: That’s why the robots who raised them beat them into submission

Comment: With the greatest respect and compassion, from the perspective of we 50+ yo everyone below the age of 23 is a child having entirely insufficient adult life experience.  Children don't organize (they think they do), they react, usually from the perspective of "me!"  And you're not even dealing with teenagers - you're dealing with the 6yo mentality (babies!).  I apologize, but your premise is very, very unrealistic (except to those under the age of 23).

Comment: @JBH: Woah woah, your more than 50! So, what was it like living with dinosaurs?

Comment: @JasperR., they were good smoked with [Sigillaria](https://www.tentree.com/blogs/posts/10-of-the-most-fascinating-extinct-trees) chips.

Comment: @JBH: Ummm.... is that why their extinct?

Comment: Are there sticks? Romans used them for the decimatio.

Comment: @JasperR. there were a lot of dinosaurs... no use letting good BBQ go to waste.

Comment: @JBH: We should clone up a few ‘em and have a big ol’ BBQ.

Comment: Surely they have _some_ small heavy objects at hand. Paperweights, even. Nuts? Bolts? Nothing? BTW, is there anything, physically or otherwise, distinctly different between the three castes? How do they group them? Is the breeder class exclusively female? If not, how does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Function of Stoning**

Your childish colonists could perform a ritual somewhat similar to stoning called "Running the Gauntlet." The accused is forced to run between two rows of people armed with blunt objects who will beat them as they run. It can be a simple embarrassment ritual where the blows are light and mostly ceremonial as the community shames the individual with laughter and mock blows or blows from painful but nonlethal objects like light branches, or it can be intended to be quite lethal as well with everyone essentially mob-beating them to death.

The purpose of execution methods like stoning is psychological, it makes the entire group complicit in the killing. It is a powerful psychological bond because it essentially forces the entire community to share the guilt of the death, and also holds the entire community responsible for policing and carrying out the punishments for the laws of said group. Stoning is one such method, the roman legions sometimes performed decimation, where every 10th man from a unit would be beaten to death by his comrades. I think running the gauntlet serves this function pretty well too.

Comment: What’s stopping the gun from just running away from the gauntlet?

Comment: Because Guns are inanimate objects?(I kid, I kid) An angry mob is a powerful thing. You have the power of dozens of people pulling you and pushing you wherever the mob wants you to go. You cant fight several dozen people, you are simply drug and herded along by a rain of blows from blunt objects, punches, and kicks until the mob is satisfied. If that satisfaction requires death you will die, if its just humiliation.... you might still die, things can get out of hand pretty easily and it only takes one good hit to the right spot and you aren't getting back up without access to a real hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute anything of similar weight.
What is on the ship?
What grows in the landscape?
what sort of trash/debris do they have?

You can also think through what sort of story you are trying to tell, because the object you settle on could have symbolic significance, either to the narrative, or to the characters, or both.

For example, what would the implications be of having them 'stone' one another with defunct mechanical parts of the derelict ship? Are there interesting stories about the 'sins of the ancestors' that might tie into?
And how would they feel about the ship, would they use it's broken down pieces for something like that, or would they revere it as an artifact?

The bottom line is you can substitute nearly anything you want: branches, bones, broken machinery, but you'd need to think about your setting and intent.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT AS PER COMMENT:**

**PREMISE:** Ok, so there is a problem of mental development: the mind of a child in the body of an adult. They just couldn't organize themselves in the society you described. Basically, without adult supervision, a kid is mentally an anarchic, and these are overgrown children. Their leaders will be just stronger bullies, without mental maturity, that can be overthrown overnight.

**ANSWER:** But even if, and that is a long stretch in logic, they managed to become an efficient community, they'd still react very violently, and without finesses, toward a tort. No stoning means that they'd crowd around their victim and club him, kick him, punch, bite...do whatever their primal response suggests. When rage sets in a child, his mind becomes too obsessed with it and the pleasure he gets from venting mindlessly until he runs out of adrenaline and will feel dazed. With an adolescent body, this means that whoever enrages the others, whatever the reason, he's in for one ugly demise

Comment: This is very informative, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The garnet actually 6 year olds, just 14yo with the mentality of 6yo. They know how to hunt and grow food. They’ve also discovered a small forest, 2 miles away, were they can gets some of the fruit.

Comment: edited: Hope it helps now